# Java Servlets: How to share common behaviour among multiple servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

Let's say I have multiple servlets with minor differences in doPost() implementation. Example code [here](https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/9231312). I want to be able to define function just once and avoid duplication of code among different servlets.

One way is to put common behaviour in a different class altogether and have object of that class in every Servlet to use common behaviour but would that be a good idea?

What are some other alternatives to tackle this issue?

Comment: Are you asking for a singleton?

Comment: You can create an abstract class which extends `Servlet` without implementing `doGet()` and make your servlets extend that class

Comment: If you *are* asking for a singleton, then you probably shouldn't be!

Comment: I edited the question to add more clarity. I hope now its clear that I'm not asking for singleton. - @AndersR.Bystrup

Comment: Nope, please re-read the question. I've tried to clarify it with an example. @BrianAgnew

Answer (score 1):

You might create an abstract class that implements Httpservlet and defines all the common methods, but leaves your modifiable (doGet) method abstract.

Comment: I tried that putting common init() code of the abstract superclass. Let's assume init() is a memory intensive operation. Then, it will be called for each child class (actual servlets, which is fine) but also for abstract base class which is not desirable.

Comment: @Anarki If you make doGet and doPost methods abstract, then at each class which is extending it you have to implement the doPost and get methods even if you don't need them. IMHO, In your case it would be better to implement them by default behaviour in parent class as: super.doGet or post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

> One way is to put common behaviour in an altogether different class and have
>   object of that class in every Servlet to use common functionality but
>   that is not very elegant

is actually quite elegant. It sound like you're describing [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). It reduces code duplication, extracts common functionality into a single component and mitigates the [issues you'd get through implementation inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Benefits).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "brittle linkage you'd get through implementation inheritance". Please elaborate?

Comment: One downside of implementation inheritance is that changes to a base class have to be reflected or accommodated through the hierarchy. See the link I edited. Often (but not always) a composition-based approach buys you flexibility and some immunity to change

Answer (score 0):

You can create a abstract superclass that extends `HttpServlet` where you put common code. Now your implementation classes may extend abstract class.

Comment: I tried that putting common init() code of the abstract superclass. Let's assume init() is a memory intensive operation. Then, it will be called for each child class (actual servlets, which is fine) but also for abstract base class which is not desirable.

Comment: Actually, `init()` wouldn't be called for the abstract base class, as it's not directly used by the servlet engine. Furthermore, methods are never directly called on abstract classes, as there are no instances (by definition) of abstract classes.